# Check for Valid Image using getFilesAsync()

Tags: png, jpeg, winjs, gif, getfiles

Using WinJS, while looping through a directory, how to retrieve only images in that particular directory and ignoring any other file extension, including the DoubleDots `..` and the SingleDot `.` etc?

Something like:

```
var dir = Windows.Storage.KnownFolders.picturesLibrary;

dir.getFilesAsync().done(function (filesFound) {

for(var i=0; i < filesFound.length; i++){}

       if(filesFound[i] IS_REALLY_AN_IMAGE_(jpeg,jpg,png,gif Only)){

       //Retrieve it now!

}else{
     //Escape it.
} 
}})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of trying to process pathnames, it will work much better to use a file query, which lets the file system do the search/filtering for you. A query also allows you to listen for the query's contentschanged event if you want to dynamically track the folder contents rather than explicitly enumerating again.

A query is created via StorageFolder.createFileQuery, createFolderQuery, or other variants. In your particular case, where you want to filter by file types, you can use [createFileQueryWithOptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br211591.aspx). This function takes a [QueryOptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.search.queryoptions.aspx) object which you can initialize with an array of file types. For example:

```
var picturesLibrary = Windows.Storage.KnownFolders.picturesLibrary;

var options = new Windows.Storage.Search.QueryOptions(
    Windows.Storage.Search.CommonFileQuery.orderByName, [".jpg", ".jpeg", ".png", ".gif"]);

//Could also use orderByDate instead of orderByName

if (picturesLibrary.areQueryOptionsSupported(options)) {
    var query = picturesLibrary.createFileQueryWithOptions(options);
    showResults(query.getFilesAsync());
}
```

where showResults is some function that takes the promise from query.getFilesAsync and iterates as needed.

I go into this subject at length in Chapter 11 of my free ebook, [*Programming Windows Store Apps with HTML, CSS, and JavaScript, 2nd Edition*](http://aka.ms/BrockschmidtBook2), in the section "Folders and Folder Queries". Also refer to the [Programmatic file search sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Programmatically-searching-25e1a56b), as I do in the book.

When you want to display the image files, be sure to use *thumbnails* instead of loading the whole image (images are typically much larger than a display). That is, for each `StorageFile`, call its `getThumbnailAsync` or `getScaledImageAsThumbnailAsync` method. Pass the resulting *thumbnail* `(blob)` to `URL.createObjectURL` which returns a `URL` you can assign to an `img.src attribute`. Or you can use a `WinJS.UI.ListView` control, but that's another topic altogether (see Chapter 7 of my book).

Comment: Thanks for the insight. But how would you display those images in an HTML `<div id="imageLand">` tag in this format something like `'<img src="THE_SOURCE_OF_THE_IMAGE" />'`??.. in `jQuery` I could do: `$('#imageLand').append('<img src="THE_SOURCE_OF_THE_IMAGE" />')` ... How can this be done using your solution in `WinJS`?.... Thanks again

Comment: For each StorageFile, call its getThumbnailAsync or getScaledImageAsThumbnailAsync method, which is more efficient than using the whole file contents. Pass the resulting thumbnail (blob) to URL.createObjectURL which returns a URL you can assign to an img.src attribute. Or you can use a WinJS.UI.ListView control, but that's another topic altogether (see Chapter 7 of my book :))

Comment: Superb!.. that shines lots of light. One request, can you please combine this comment with your answer for legibility purpose?.. Again thank you very much!

Comment: Done. By the way. I see you also asked this question on the MSDN forum. I'm going to post the same answer there.

Comment: Thanks again... Am gonna mark this as the Answer and do the same in MSDN... Thanks again!